# Java: how to read options from command line like -input or --h?

Tags: java, parsing, command-line

Searched for a while now...
I don't want to use a special parser, just build-in methods.

The problem is I want to read options like `-i=something` in a simple way.
Then - in the script - I can call these options like `args[i]` or so.

Is there any way?
Thanks

EDIT: Example

Command Line: `java scriptname -write="test"`

Script: `System.out.println(args[write]);`

Output: `test`

Comment: String[] args isn't working for you?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you add example of where you are using such options? If it is in `java YourClass options` then they are automatically moved to `args` array so I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: To add more detail to question use [edit] option placed below your post.

Comment: No, I just wondered if there is an easy-to-use method to read these parameters... Not by index, I want to get a kind of dictionary from the input

Comment: Like I said, [edit] your question and provide example of input and expected result (preferably with explanation why such result should be expected). Without it your question stays very unclear which attracts more downvotes (which may cause question ban).

Comment: If you want to get a kind of dictionary from the input, loop over the array and put them into a map. Or any other data structure you please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to you pass parameters as key-value pairs while invoking java program, you can do that using `-D` flag like this

```
java -Demail=test@gmail.com -DuserName="John Watson" MainProgam
```

If your value has spaces in it, enclose that in double quotes. Now
you can access these values as system properties in your code like this

```
String email = System.getProperty("email");
String name = System.getProperty("userName");
```

All the parameters passed after class name in `java` command are accessible in `args[]` of main method, you can access them only through indices not with key value pairs

Comment: glad to be of help :)